# How to get an access token in JWT format in Flutter's google_sign_in?

Tags: api, flutter, google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints

I am authenticating calls to a private API running on GCP behind GCP Cloud Endpoints as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-google-id).

It is working ok, but for each call I am using `GoogleSignInAuthentication.idToken` that contains user's profile information and generally too much information for access.

`GoogleSignInAuthentication.authToken`  and `GoogleSignInAccount.authHeaders` are not in JWT format and are being rejected by Endpoints.

Is there a way to get access token in JWT format in `google_sing_in`? Or maybe it is ok to use the id token for each call?

Comment: Google OAuth Access Tokens are not JWTs. They are opaque tokens. Use the OAuth Identity Tokens. How much information (claims) is contained in an Identity Token is affected by the request scopes (opened, email, profile). https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#discovery

Answer (score 1):

The `idToken` provided by the Google Sign In libraries is already an Open Id Connect Token as you can see in this [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAuthentication-class.html), that means it already comes in a secure JWT format, so yeah, it definately ok to use it.

The Google Sign In libraries also offer a OAuth2 access token which can be called with `GoogleSignInAuthentication.accessToken`, by using that you might be able to generate a token in JWT format.

So it's really up to you, personally I would use the provided `idToken`, as it ready for you to use already.